# Convert a list into 2-D array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, matplotlib, colorbar

I am trying to create a plot and the points are shaded with a colorbar.

```
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x,y, c=time_color)
```

I have a time_color list, e.g.

```
time_color = [0, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 3, 2]
```

Unfortunately, the plot command will not accept a list to specify color. So I converted it to an array

```
numpy.array(time_color)
```

This gave me a one dimensional array.

```
numpy.ndim(numpy.array(time_color))
```

How can I convert a list into a 2 dimensional array to produce a 3-D plot (the third dimension being color)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, matplotlib's scatter plot does accept a list for the colorbar. 
For instance, following is perfectly legal and creates a 2D plot with color being the 3rd dimension:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter( range(0,10), range(0,10), c=range(0,10) )
```

[image]

If you would like a 3D plot with color being the fourth dimension, you can use the same idea:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig) #Or: ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.scatter( range(0,10), range(0,10), c=range(0,10) )
```

[image]

Comment: So did my answer best resolved your question? I'd much appreciate if you could vote up my answer for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy.reshape` to change the dimension of your `numpy` array. For instance you can do as following:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> time_color = [0, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 3, 2]
>>> numpy.array(time_color)
array([0, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5, 4, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 3, 2])
>>> numpy.reshape(time_color, (3, 7))
array([[0, 4, 3, 3, 2, 3, 5],
       [4, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5, 1, 4, 3, 2]])
```

or in the case your `time_color` array has `len(x)` elements you can *reshape* your `time_color` list as following (where`len(x)=n*m`):

```
>>> numpy.reshape(time_color, (m, n))
```